# How do i Log in in a webservice using my android App?

Tags: android

I am trying to log in in the website through my app.
I am using volley library. I am not able to figure out how should i send the data and what exactly is the response that i will get?

the URL is http://saptrishiherbal.com/home/login

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button login;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;

    String url = "http://www.saptrishiherbal.com/home/login";
    String Username;
    String Password;

    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "txtusername";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "txtPassword";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);

        Username = username.getText().toString().trim();
        Password = password.getText().toString().trim();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Loginnow(Username, Password);
            }
        });    
    }

    public void Loginnow(final String username1, final String password1) {

        final HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put(KEY_USERNAME, username1);
        params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password1);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new String(params), new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Home.class);
                startActivity(intent);    
            }
        },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })

       /* {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_USERNAME, username1);
                params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password1);

                return params;    
            }

        };*/

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);    
        showpDialog();    
    }

    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }    
}
```

Comment: as you said that, you are getting HTML code in response, then problem is from back end side... Make that change first and then check if you are getting proper response.

Comment: okay so its a login page and it directs to the next page if correct credentials are entered. generally, in this case what should be the response from the server?

Comment: It should be the json response from server like this: http://pastebin.com/exhSQg7U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use POSTMAN to hit the API url and view the response.

Login is usually a post request with the credentials in body of the app.
If the credentials are in params and not body, it could be either GET or POST request.

Once you figured out the HTTP method type and where params are to be placed, you can create Volley request for that method and override getParams() or getBody() methods as required.

Comment: I did check the response in POSTMAN. and it is showing an html code with username and password as fields. i am using GET method but due to some reason i am not getting any response. I have also posted my code please do check it. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure what you are sending the request to is an API URL?

Comment: i have mentioned the url in my question so i would really appreciate it if you could check that. i am kinda stuck here.

Comment: so i went to the URL and turns out this is the [http://saptrishiherbal.com/requests/loginc](URL) you need to send the request to. You will have to send a POST request.
[https://s12.postimg.org/dix662irh/Capture.png]Here is the screen cap of the captured request. Try hitting it successfully with POSTMAN and then include the body content by over riding the getBody() method of Volley
 I suggest a StringRequest using volley. In the on response method, you can parse the string response to JSON and get data as per your requirement.

Comment: so i went to the URL and turns out this is the URL saptrishiherbal.com/requests/loginc you need to send the request to. You will have to send a POST request. s12.postimg.org/dix662irh/Capture.png Here is the screen cap of the captured request. Try hitting it successfully with POSTMAN and then include the body content you used in PostMan to your app by over riding the getBody() method of Volley.
 I suggest a StringRequest using volley. In the on response method, you can parse the string response to JSON and get data as per your requirement

Comment: thanks for your effort. i tried the url u gave in  POSTMAN and it is not giving any response. it's showing and error. for POST method it throws 500 internal server error. also, the screenshot that u shared what was the app you used to find out the url that i need to send the request to?

Comment: It's google developer console. Just press ctrl+shift+i and go to network.

Comment: Turns out this URL isn't an API url and hence it can not be accessed via postman or volley. You will have to change the code at the backend to alter the current action or to create an API